# Expanding search bar over links that fits my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery/Javascript isn't my strongest skill so I'm asking for some help. What I'm looking for is once you click an image, a search bar comes out and extends to the left of the image. When the image is clicked again, it retracts. I know it can be done with a couple lines of Javascript but I have a hard time putting it all together.

If you go to my the fiddle I've created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/incredifull/7R77j/), you will see the image I'm talking about in the navigation bar is a magnify glass. This is what I'd like clicked on so that it extends to the left. I'd like for it to extend to cover the social media, email and login buttons, but not too much further.

To get even more of a vision of exactly what I'd like, visit [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/). This is exactly what I want in every way possible... just more fit to my website.

The *#tools-nav .search* at the bottom of the CSS is the search part.

What I have for my navigation CSS is:

```
/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
height: 40px;
width: 961px;
background: #1e416f;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#navi a:hover {
background: white;
color: #1e416f;
}

#navi .logo {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#navi .logo a {
float: left;
width: 56px;
height: 40px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) center no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) center no-repeat;
background-color: white;
}

#primary-nav, #tools-nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#primary-nav li, #primary-nav a, #tools-nav li, #tools-nav a {
float: left;
}

#primary-nav a, #tools-nav a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
line-height: 40px;
}

#tools-nav a:hover {
color: #1e416f;
}

#primary-nav li:first-child a, #tools-nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#tools-nav {
float: right;
}

#tools-nav .icon a {
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#tools-nav .email a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .email a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_mail.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover-twitter.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_search.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
width: 20px;
}
```

And my relevant HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="navi">
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a *Fiddle* to indicate the issue better. You're using  relative paths to address images in your stylesheet, use a placeholder  instead.

Comment: @HashemQolami Sorry about that! Just added a link to the fiddle I've created.

Comment: I've posted two solution to implement the animation, please give it a try and let me know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to mess with your code, because it will be too complicated to show you the result. Here is a jsfiddle with the task implemented http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/tELy5/1/

Here is the solution implemented into your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/7R77j/8/

The idea is to have two classes and swap them once the button is clicked. The first class hides the search field and the second one shows it. If you set the transition property then the input is animated.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">T</a>
    <a href="#">F</a>
    <a href="#">L</a>
    <a href="#" id="search">S</a>
</nav>
<input type="text" id="search-field" class="search-field search-field-hidden" />
```

JS

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById("search"),
    searchField = document.getElementById("search-field");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(searchField.className.indexOf("search-field-shown") > 0) {
        searchField.className = "search-field search-field-hidden";
        searchField.blur();
    } else {
        searchField.className = "search-field search-field-shown";
        searchField.focus();
    }        
});
```

CSS

```
nav:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #999;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
a:hover{
    background: #000;
}
.search-field {
    border: solid 2px #999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    display: block;
    height: 23px;
    width: 86px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms;
}
.search-field-shown {
    left: 6px;
    width: 86px;
}
.search-field-hidden {
    left: 90px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Do you think you're able to mess around with the Fiddle I've provided and implement this? I'm trying to do so but luck I said... my knowledge isn't great with this. So far I have this which includes your work and mine: http://jsfiddle.net/incredifull/7R77j/1/

Comment: Yep, I'll do that. I just wrote my answer before your jsfiddle appearance.

Comment: Here it is the solution implemented into your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/7R77j/8/

Answer (score 1):

I used CSS3 `transition` to implement the animation you're looking for. Also jQuery is used to toggle the active class on search `<input>`:

**HTML:**

```html
<li class="search icon">
    <a href="#">Search</a>
    <input type="text" />
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#tools-nav li { position: relative; }

li.search input {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li.search input.active {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 151px;
    left: -151px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```css
jQuery(function($) {
    $('li.search').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('input').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is the **[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7R77j/3/)**.

### Update

Since old web browsers do not support CSS3 `transition` property, you might want to consider using jQuery `.animate()` method to implement the animation.

In this case, we don't need to declare CSS style on `.active` class.

Here is the **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7R77j/5/)**.